# Foundation Featured Images in a Responsive Grid

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation-6

I am trying various solutions for building a small grid of featured images for a blog, that is, a horizontal display of up to three images overlaid with text linking to a blog-post. Specifically, I need it do respond well to different screen sizes through at most three images in a row. Thus, like the following:

[image]

As I am using Foundation (6) I'd like to rely on it for the Responsive Grid. I have tried out the [Block Grids](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html#block-grids), but have had problems keeping the overlaid text positioned when adding padding between them. Consider the following example (not using block grids, as they stack vertically):

```css
.featured .menu li {
  position: relative;
}
.featured .menu li article {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.25em;
}
.featured .menu li a {
  margin: 0;
}
.featured .menu li p {
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}
.featured .menu li p:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: .6;
  z-index: -1;
  background: #ffffff;
}
.featured .menu li img {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.0.1/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container featured">
  <ul class="menu expanded">
    <li>
      <article>
        <a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Long Post Title" itemprop="url">
          <p>Long Post Title</p>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150">
        </a>
      </article>
    </li>
    <li>
      <article>
        <a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Long Post Title" itemprop="url">
          <p>Long Post Title</p>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150">
        </a>
      </article>
    </li>
    <li>
      <article>
        <a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Long Post Title" itemprop="url">
          <p>Long Post Title</p>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150">
        </a>
      </article>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The keen of eye will notice that the paragraph-element does not conform to the width of the parent article-element. Thus, the question has two components:

- How can I restrict the width of the paragraph of overlaid text to fit the parent element, whilst allowing space between the images and a even distribution of them within the row?
- What would an implementation using Foundation's responsive grids (or other component) look like, with the added constraint that the images remain in one row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what I set out to do I found it easier using Foundation 6's Flex-Grid ([not enabled by default](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/flex-grid.html) in F6, [see source](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/36234-flex-grid-in-css) and [Gist](https://gist.github.com/OleVik/f885e51ba3fe8a6d07e7#file-foundation-flex-css)) rather than the Grid or Block-Grid, for it's ease in centering the blocks without much added CSS. Here is the solution I landed on:

```css
.featured {
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.featured .column {
  padding-left: 0.25rem;
  padding-right: 0.25rem;
}
.featured .column {
  position: relative;
}
.featured .column article {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.featured .column article header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.featured .column header h3 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: Open Sans, MundoSans, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}
.featured .column header h3 span {
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.featured .column section.post-image {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 14em;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-position: center;
}
.featured .column section.post-image img {
  opacity: 0;
}
.featured .column section.post-image:after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  content: "";
  z-index: 0;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=0);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 32em) {
  /* Small: any screen */
  .featured .column:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+10) {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 32em) and (max-width: 64em) {
  /* Medium: any screen 640 pixels or wider */
  .featured .column:nth-child(n+4):nth-child(-n+10) {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 64em) {
  /* Large: any screen 1024 pixels or wider */
  .featured .column:nth-child(n+5):nth-child(-n+10) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/OleVik/f885e51ba3fe8a6d07e7/raw/4ad1d46ee2c1139528cc727d055be9bfe2912d41/foundation.flex.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container featured">
  <div class="row align-justify">
    <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-3 small-centered column">
      <article>
        <a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Long Post Title" itemprop="url">
          <section class="post-image" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/500x150')">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/500x150" />
          </section>
          <header>
            <h3><span>Long Post Title</span></h3>
          </header>
        </a>

      </article>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-3 small-centered column">
      <article>
        <a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Long Post Title" itemprop="url">
          <section class="post-image" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/500x150')">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/500x150" />
          </section>
          <header>
            <h3><span>Long Post Title</span></h3>
          </header>
        </a>

      </article>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-3 small-centered column">
      <article>
        <a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Long Post Title" itemprop="url">
          <section class="post-image" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/500x150')">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/500x150" />
          </section>
          <header>
            <h3><span>Long Post Title</span></h3>
          </header>
        </a>

      </article>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-3 small-centered column">
      <article>
        <a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Long Post Title" itemprop="url">
          <section class="post-image" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/500x150')">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/500x150" />
          </section>
          <header>
            <h3><span>Long Post Title</span></h3>
          </header>
        </a>

      </article>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-3 small-centered column">
      <article>
        <a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Long Post Title" itemprop="url">
          <section class="post-image" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/500x150')">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/500x150" />
          </section>
          <header>
            <h3><span>Long Post Title</span></h3>
          </header>
        </a>

      </article>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-3 small-centered column">
      <article>
        <a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Long Post Title" itemprop="url">
          <section class="post-image" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/500x150')">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/500x150" />
          </section>
          <header>
            <h3><span>Long Post Title</span></h3>
          </header>
        </a>

      </article>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-3 small-centered column">
      <article>
        <a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Long Post Title" itemprop="url">
          <section class="post-image" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/500x150')">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/500x150" />
          </section>
          <header>
            <h3><span>Long Post Title</span></h3>
          </header>
        </a>

      </article>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-3 small-centered column">
      <article>
        <a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Long Post Title" itemprop="url">
          <section class="post-image" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/500x150')">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/500x150" />
          </section>
          <header>
            <h3><span>Long Post Title</span></h3>
          </header>
        </a>

      </article>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-3 small-centered column">
      <article>
        <a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Long Post Title" itemprop="url">
          <section class="post-image" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/500x150')">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/500x150" />
          </section>
          <header>
            <h3><span>Long Post Title</span></h3>
          </header>
        </a>

      </article>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-3 small-centered column">
      <article>
        <a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Long Post Title" itemprop="url">
          <section class="post-image" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/500x150')">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/500x150" />
          </section>
          <header>
            <h3><span>Long Post Title</span></h3>
          </header>
        </a>

      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It does the following:

- Creates a Foundation 6 Flex-Grid.
- Blocks use inline CSS (background image) to compensate for uneven sizes and for lightbox compatibility, and are evenly distributed (justified) with gradient overlay.
- Overlays text (with colored background).
- Limits blocks to one row using Foundation and media-query CSS: 4 blocks on large screens, 3 on medium, 1 on small.

See [JSFiddle-result](https://jsfiddle.net/sb6uedbc/8/embedded/result/) and [Source](https://jsfiddle.net/sb6uedbc/8/).